# Centos 7 Policy Based Routing not working CEntos 6 no problem

Tags: centos, routing, iproute

Centos  7 Policy Based Routing   not working CEntos 6 no problem

How can i transfer my static based routing policies from Centos 6 to 7 ...

I have two WAN ip/gateways, 1 LAN  ip address on on NIC . .

Centos6:
eth0 10.10.10.150
eth0.2 6.6.6.6 (example wan)
eth0:3 7.6.6.6 (example wan2)

works great with routing tables, t1/t2

How can i get that in to Centos 7? it seems buggy/confusing. .

even creating a virtual interface (wlan2) alone on centos 7 on the same subnet,  i can not even ping it from other clients, which would require no gateway . ip tables off.

Thank you in advance.